# Invalid Label Error with JSON request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I've read about this a lot and I just can't figure it out. It has nothing to do with MY code, it has to do with the feed or something because if I swap it with a Twitter feed it returns an Object object which is perfect.

```
$.getJSON('http://rockbottom.nozzlmedia.com:8000/api/portland/?count=1&callback=?',function(json){
    console.log(json)
});
```

And i get an "invalid label" error. Any ideas?

Also, a side note, I've tried the AJAX method as well:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://rockbottom.nozzlmedia.com:8000/api/portland/',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: 'count=1',
    success: function(msg){
        console.log(msg)
    }
});
```

and both give the same exact error, and both work fine with Flickr and Twitter examples, so it must be something to do with the feed, but I dont have access to the feed, but I could ask them to fix something IF it's their issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that the server side can handle the JSONP request properly. See [here](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/107136.aspx) for example.

**Edit**: It seems that the server doesn't wrap the returned JSON object with the callback function name. The server should return:

```
callback( { json here } )
```

and not

```
{ json here }
```

Comment: I dont have access to the feed, so, how can I check if it's set up right? I did notice though that I can't add callbacks to the feed like Flickr and Twitter and most other APIs. Is there a test i can do and then a result I can send the developer to have him fix it?

Comment: See my edited answer. As it is now the server doesn't support jsonp calls.

Comment: damn it, thank you though, i think i'll cURL it then :) thank you!

Answer (score 2):

That URL looks like it's expecting you to provide a [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) callback (from the `callback=?` bit). That's probably the problem; it's returning Javascript rather than JSON (because that's how JSONP works). See the [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) docs for more about using JSONP services.

Comment: See my comment above. I know about callback=? and jsonp, and like above says, it works with Twitter and Flickr... :( Is it the actual JSON?

Comment: @Oscar: Certainly sounds like it could be, you'll need to look at what comes back.

Answer (score 0):

The returned content has unescaped double-quotes in one of the strings. It's invalid JSON:

```
..."full_content":"just voted "with Mandy " on...
```

Comment: Will that give that error? Im refreshing it and it has new content and this time it doesnt have that or the escaped quotes and i did validate it (i thought it was invalid as well), but it passed, obviously the sample you gave ISNT valid, but the others seem to be. I dont have access to the feed code tho, so, if you know any workarounds let me know :)