# Why "SyntaxError: invalid label" when trying to use $.ajax to get JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to use [Viralheat's API](https://app.viralheat.com/developer) to do sentiment analysis using jQuery.

**1. When I type this in the browser's address bar, it's OK:**

```
https://app.viralheat.com/social/api/sentiment?api_key=1234&text=Schindler%27s%20List
```

And it shows:

```
{"status":403,"error":"API Key not registered"}
```

**2. Using these lines of code, the web page shows error and I suppose it runs into the same origin policy:**

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: "https://app.viralheat.com/social/api/sentiment?api_key=1234&text=Schindler's List",
        success: function(data){alert(data);},
        error: function(){alert("error");}
    });
```

**3. When I add a `callback=?` into the url, and `dataType: 'json',`using firebug, I can see the same result with scenario 1`{"status":403,"error":"API Key not registered"}`, but the web page still shows error, and an error occurs: SyntaxError: invalid label**

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "https://app.viralheat.com/social/api/sentiment?api_key=1234&text=Schindler's List&callback=?",
        success: function(data){alert(data);},
        error: function(){alert("error");}
    });
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "the web page still shows error"?  If there's further javascript that inserts something into the page, where is it?

Comment: I mean `alert("error");` still executes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invalid Label Error with JSON request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816653/invalid-label-error-with-json-request)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Merely adding `callback=whatever` to a JSON API request will not magically turn the result into JSONP, unless the service actually supports a JSONP option like that.

The Viralheat API you're using does not appear to support JSONP. [The documentation](https://app.viralheat.com/developer/sentiment) says nothing about a JSONP option of any sort. The only options it mentions are the `API_KEY` and `TEXT` PARAMETERS.

As you discovered, adding `callback=anything` doesn't change the output format from JSON to JSONP. If you try [your API call with a `callback=foobar` parameter added](https://app.viralheat.com/social/api/sentiment?api_key=1234&text=Schindler%27s%20List&callback=foobar), it still produces ordinary JSON:

```
{
    "status": 403,
    "error": "API Key not registered"
}
```

If this service doesn't support JSONP or [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), you will have to use code on your server to access the service instead of JavaScript in a client's browser.